# how to load css and font locally for jHipster 7

Tags: angular, spring-boot, bootstrap-4, jhipster

i noticed that my projet is loading css and fonts online , so when my laptop is offline the project is loaded with no css , i have searched how to load css locally but it looks no much documentation about that.

in index.html i have noticed that jHipster add the url to load fonts and css after this comment

```
 <!-- jhipster-needle-add-resources-to-root - JHipster will add new resources here -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce this issue by turning off my internet connection and running `./mvnw clean` and `./mvnw spring-boot:run` on my [jhipster7-demo](https://github.com/mraible/jhipster7-demo) project. Everything renders just fine. I also tried with JHipster 8 and didn't have any issues.

Comment: thx for your answer. but maybe you had already all resources cached , try to run the app from another session in browser without internet.

Comment: I tried again and used a couple of browsers in incognito mode. I still can't reproduce the problem. Maybe someone modified your app to load its resources from the web? This is not the default behavior in a newly-generated JHipster project.